# Need waypoints repeating on multiple items

Tags: jquery-waypoints

Here's my code, lifted from waypoints docs:

```
var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
element: $('.objectheader')[0]
})


<div class="object" id="object2">
    <div class="objectheader" id="header2">Header Item 2</div>
    <div class="objectbody" id="body2"><img src="images/samplechart.png" /></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, I have multiple objects (the list will grow, so hard coding for each ID isn't an option) that each contain an objectheader and objectbody.  Every time I hit an objectheader, I want it to apply the sticky class and stick at the top until it reaches a new one, however it's only working on the first object.  I know I'm missing something simple here...

Answer (score 0):

with `[0]` you are specifying the very first element. You need to iterate over them to add a waypoint to each element...

```
var sticky = [];
$('.objectheader').each(function(idx){
    sticky[idx] = new Waypoint.Sticky({ element: this });
});
```

then `sticky` will be an array of all your waypoint objects.

Comment: Great! If you consider the question answered, you can mark this as correct and upvote if useful. Welcome to stack overflow!